# Can I use Type 2 JDBC Driver to call a SP from within java without passing username and password?

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, driver

My Java app is getting called form withing a shell script and Java app is then calling a Stored procedure. It was working all fine till the time I was using Type 4 Drivers but not working when tried to use Type 2 drivers . We must not use password to connect to Database through java which resulted in going for Type 2 drivers. 
I am getting below error when trying with type 2 :

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.61.86] Failure
>   in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   db2jcct2 (Not found in java.library.path):  ERRORCODE=-4472,
>   SQLSTATE=null

Tried setting path of the native library as well for 64 bits as the database is 64 bit  , using :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/prods/db2/USH25D/sqllib/lib64
```

Nothing seems to be working . But the question is does TYPE2 Drivers support Stored Procedure calls for the SPs which return values ?
 If this is not supported then the efforts to make it working will go invain

Comment: For the load ailure, Check https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978   (and know the bitness of your jvm/jre, and also whose jre you are using, i.e. the one supplied by Db2 or Oracle etc.)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to set the native library path, and it's not with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your actual problem, which is that the type 2 driver needs to load a native library and can't find it. In any case, I would be surprised if the type 2 driver wouldn't support something this basic that the type 4 driver does support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not constructive.

Comment: Yes@mustaccio the title is different because I know that the problem I am facing can be resolved but my main question was (which I mentioned in the end as well in the description) Can we use TYPE 2 drivers to call SPs which return values . I read somehwere which says TYPE 2 only support calling SPs which dont return values .

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I ignore the load-failure message and respond to the questions relating to Db2 Type-2 jdbc connectivity capabilities.

Starting from Db2-LUW V11.1 IBM [deprecated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvintro.html) "db2jcc.jar" which means it won't get any new features although fixes will continue to be delivered.

The currently supported versions of the Db2 jdbc driver support *both* Type-2 connections and Type-4 connections including both types concurrentl, as IBM specifies:
:

> "The IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ is a single driver that
>   includes JDBC type 2 and JDBC type 4 behavior. When an application
>   loads the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ, a single driver
>   instance is loaded for type 2 and type 4 implementations. The
>   application can make type 2 and type 4 connections using this single
>   driver instance. The type 2 and type 4 connections can be made
>   concurrently. IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 2 driver
>   behavior is referred to as IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
>   type 2 connectivity. IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 4
>   driver behavior is referred to as IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and
>   SQLJ type 4 connectivity."

So when I use the Type-2 URL format (`jdbc:db2:mydbname`) for passwordless local connections via the DriverManager interface, it connects successfully when db2jcc4.jar is at the start of the CLASSPATH and db2jcc.jar is not on the CLASSPATH.

It also lets jdbc call an SQL PL stored-procedure that returns an output parameter (which is correctly retrieved) along with result-set etc.

So apart from the URL, I don't know what else you need to change *if* you are using a current version of db2jcc4.jar - subject to careful testing as usual.